# Matlab DWT H-level

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I'm trying to implement some watermarking algorithm found in a paper*. This is a line of the paper:

> Do the H-level DWT for all the renumbered segments.

Then in simulation section the author explains the wavelet used for experiments.

> DWT transform adopted the common wavelet "Daubechies-1" and level H =
>   3.

I just don't get what does H means, how do I input H=3 in matlab DWT function?

My actual code is:

```
[cA,cD] = dwt(audio,'db1');
```

Can someone help me?

*Ji, Y. & Kim, J. A Quantified Audio Watermarking Algorithm Based on DWT-DCT. Multimedia, Computer Graphics and Broadcasting 339–344 (2011)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

intuitively speaking, H-level define how many level of DWT you need to perform on your signal in this case you need to perform 3rd level "Daubechies-1" wavelet Transform on your Signal, what that really mean is applying DWT on your signal 3 times,

This is how you are suppose to do that,

Apply DWT on your Signal to decompose it into `Approximations` (low-frequency) and `Details` (High-frequency). This is level 1 decomposition, according to your requirements we need to perform level 3 DWT therefore we will pick the Approximation(lets say `a1`) of the above decomposed signal and again apply DWT to decompose it into more deep Approximations (let say `a2`) and details (`d2`), Now do it one more time for level 3.

this is simple demonstration I've done using Matlab Wavelet toolbox,

[image]

S is the original signal (`noissin` in this case; which is a built-in waveform in matlab) which is decomposed in `a1` and `d1` we then picked `a1` and applied DWT on this signal again to get `a2` and `d2`; `a2` is further decomposed in `a3` and `d3`.

here is the tree view of what i said earlier.

[image]

In order to better understand how Wavelet transform works, type `wavemenu` in the matlab command window then go to Wavelet 1-D option, load any built-in signal and play around.

The built-in signal can be found in `Matlab Directory` -> `toolbox` -> `wavelet` -> `wavedemo` folder.

In order to perform perform level 3 decomposition in matlab I'd rather prefer `wavedec` instead of `dwt` because the syntax is far more easier and well explained,

here is the syntax for `wavedec`

```
[C,L] = wavedec(X,N,'wname')
```

Where,

X = your Signal to decompose.

N = Level; in your case it should be 3.

wname = Wavelet to use; in your case it should be `'db1'`

```
% L is the matrix that store length of each decomposed signal
% This is how it will be stored in Matrix of [C,L]
%----------------------------------
% C: |cA3|cD3|cD2|cD1|
%----------------------------------
%----------------------------------
% L: | (length cA3) | (length of cD3) | (length of cD2) | (length of cD1) |
%----------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I haven't seen your answer. Thank you.